# In Gittin 45a was the Captive who ידע בלישנא דציפורי a soothsayer?

Tags: talmud-gemara, birds

In [**Gittin 45a**](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.45a.19?lang=bi), we read about a Man who ידע בלישנא דציפורי **knew the language of birds**. - While in captivity with Rav Ilish, the bird translator speaks for a Raven and Dove. The Birds try to tell Rav Ilish to escape:

**Gittin 45a**

> One day a certain man was sitting with him in captivity who knew the language of birds. A raven came and called to Rav Ilish. Rav Ilish said to the man: What is the raven saying? He said to him that it is saying: Ilish, escape; Ilish, escape. Rav Ilish said: It is a lying raven, and I do not rely on it. ( יומא חד הוה יתיב גביה ההוא גברא דהוה ידע בלישנא דציפורי אתא עורבא וקא קרי ליה אמר ליה מאי קאמר אמר ליה עיליש ברח עיליש ברח אמר עורבא שיקרא הוא ולא סמיכנא עליה )

**Gittin 45a**

> In the meantime, a dove came and was calling out. Rav Ilish said to the man: What is it saying? He said to him that the dove said: Ilish, escape; Ilish, escape. Ilish said: The Congregation of Israel is compared to a dove; I conclude from the dove’s words that a miracle will happen for me, and I can attempt to escape. Rav Ilish said: Before I leave, I will go and I will see Rav Naḥman’s daughters. If they remained steadfast in their faith and are acting appropriately, then I will take them with me and I will return them to their home. ( אדהכי אתא יונה וקא קריא אמר ליה מאי קאמרה א"ל עיליש ברח עיליש ברח אמר כנסת ישראל כיונה מתילא ש"מ מתרחיש לי ניסא אמר איזיל אחזי בנתיה דרב נחמן אי קיימן בהימנותייהו אהדרינהו )

- Was the Captive who ידע בלישנא דציפורי a soothsayer interpreting signs of the birds (raven & dove) as metaphors for escaping (flying away) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ramban ([Deuteronomy 18:9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ramban_on_Deuteronomy.18.9.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) understands that this is a form of divination called טייר which was prohibited by the Torah. This science determines what will happen in the future by examining the birds' chirping and movement of wings. Presumably he had this passage in mind when he says that it's mentioned in the Gemara (and the editor adds in a reference to this passage explicitly).

> ורבים יתחסדו בנחשים לומר שאין בהם אמת כלל כי מי יגיד לעורב ולעגור מה יהיה ואנחנו לא נוכל להכחיש דברים יתפרסמו לעיני רואים ורבותינו גם כן יודו בהם כמו שאמרו בואלה שמות רבה (ויק"ר לב ב קהלת רבה י כג) כי עוף השמים יוליך את הקול (קהלת י כ) זה העורב וחכמת הטיארין העופות בלשון ערב טאי"ר וחכמי העופות יקראו טיארין ועוד מוזכר מזה הענין בגמרא (גיטין מה) ... והידיעה היא הבנת הצפצוף והערמה לסבור ענין בפרישות הכנפים